# Is it possible to use properties settings to save data in trackBar1 scroll event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this two functions to load and save settings :

```
private void GetSettings()
        {
            lblLastDownloaded.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.LastDownloadedDateTime;
            trackBar1.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.TrackBar;
        }

        private void SaveSettings()
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.LastDownloadedDateTime = lblLastDownloaded.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.TrackBar = trackBar1.Value;

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

I'm calling the GetSettings in the form1 load event :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetSettings();
        }
```

And the SaveSettings I'm calling it in two places :

Once in some function when download has finished :

```
lblLastDownloaded.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
SaveSettings();
```

The second place is in the trackBar1 scroll event because I want to save each time the user change the trackBar1 value :

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = trackBar1.Value * 100;
            timer2.Interval = trackBar1.Value * 100;

            FormatTrackBarValues();

            SaveSettings();
        }
```

The question is if it's a good idea to call the SaveSettings in the scroll event because it's saving each time also the other settings like the label text and if I will have other settings in the future.

I want to save the text to the label once but to save also each time the trackBar1 value has changed.

I could make another method specific for saving only for the trackBar1 value but that's not a solution because I don't want to make a new method for each value I want to save.

Comment: It is point-and-click, select the trackbar and assign the ApplicationSettings properties.

Comment: @HansPassant Working. Thanks.